# Rank and degree of $\mathcal{O}_{S \times S}/I_{\Delta}^n$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $S$ be a rational surface over $\mathbb{C}$.
We denote by $\Delta$ the diagonal of $S \times S$ ($\Delta \simeq S$).
Then we can consider the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{S \times S}/I_{\Delta}^n$.

> What are the rank and degree of $\mathcal{O}_{S \times S}/I^n_{\Delta}$?

Comment: Do you mean to ask about rank and degree as a sheaf on $S\times S$ or as a sheaf on $\Delta$?

Comment: @KReiser: $\mathcal{O}_{S\times S}/I^n$ is not a sheaf on $\Delta$; it is a sheaf on the $(n-1)$-st infinitesimal neighborhood of $\Delta$!

Comment: Of course, you are correct @Sasha - I just wanted to check where the sheaf was, because the question was not totally clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ is smooth, there is an isomorphism
$$
I^k/I^{k+1} \cong \Delta_*(I/I^2) \cong \Delta_*(S^k\Omega_S),
$$
where $\Delta$ is the diagonal embedding $S \to S \times S$.
Furthermore, the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{S\times S}/I^n$ has a filtration by $I^k/I^n$ with associated graded factors
$$
I^k/I^{k+1},\qquad 0 \le k \le n-1.
$$
These two observations allow to compute the invariants of $\mathcal{O}_{S\times S}/I^n$.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I will try it.